# errno to Go errors

Tags: c, go, kvm, cgo

I'm trying to issue KVM ioctls from Go code. At the moment I have something as follows:

```
func (vm *Vm) RegisterIrqFd(efd *EventFd, gsi uint32) error {
    irqfd := (*C.struct_kvm_irqfd)(C.calloc(1, C.sizeof_struct_kvm_irqfd))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(irqfd))
    irqfd.fd = C.uint(efd.Fd())
    irqfd.gsi = C.uint(gsi)
    if _, err := sysutils.Ioctl(vm.Fd(), C.KVM_IRQFD, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(irqfd))); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("RegisterIrqFd failed: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

The Ioctl function is implemented as follows :

```
func Ioctl(fd uintptr, cmd C.uint, arg uintptr) (uintptr, error) {
    ret, _, errno := syscall.Syscall(
        syscall.SYS_IOCTL,
        fd,
        uintptr(cmd),
        uintptr(arg),
    )
    if int64(ret) == -1 {
        return ret, ErrnoToErr(errno)
    }
    return ret, nil
}
```

And the ErrnoToErr function is implemented as follows :

```
func ErrnoToErr(errno syscall.Errno) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("%v", errno.Error())
}
```

1. Inside GetSupportedCpuid, the argument for the ioctl, `cpuid` is allocated using `C.calloc`. If this were C code `cpuid` could just be allocated on the stack. Is there any way I can get around allocating using calloc and using free? Any alternatives that would be more idiomatic?
2. Would there be a way to have ErrnoToErr return a go error type corresponding to the errno? Currently it uses the `(e Errno) Error()` inside syscall/syscall_unix.go; so it just dereferences a list of strings and returns the string. It would be nice to have a type, so that I can test for specific errors in my unit tests.

Comment: If you *did* allocate the cpuid data on the stack, you could not return (a pointer to) it from the function, because returning from the function would invalidate the stack storage. What's not really clear to me is how far you want to go in terms of converting from C-centric (the ioctl, to fill in a buffer whose size is determined at runtime but limited to `MaxKvmCpuidEntries`) to Go-centric (where you might want a slice of Go-ized data).

Comment: @torek Thanks-- yes, I picked the wrong ioctl to show as an example. Assuming that the cpuid did not need to be returned from the function, is there a way to allocate it on the stack? I'll go ahead and update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying just to the updated example, we could do this:

```
func (vm *Vm) RegisterIrqFd(efd *EventFd, gsi uint32) error {
    irqfd := C.struct_kvm_irqfd{}
    irqfd.fd = C.uint(efd.Fd())
    irqfd.gsi = C.uint(gsi)
    if _, err := sysutils.Ioctl(vm.Fd(), C.KVM_IRQFD, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&irqfd))); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("RegisterIrqFd failed: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I *think* this is safe, but we might find that `irqfd escapes to heap` anyway since we take its address here, in which case there's not much savings.  Even so, as long as this doesn't violate Go pointer rules (I don't think it does) it's a lot nicer to read.

Comment: Thanks! I think it needs to be "irqfd := C.struct_kvm_irqfd{}"

Comment: @learnlearnlearn: oops, yes. Quite untested, too. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Read the documentation [syscall.Errno](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Errno)

So convertion may be performed like this

```
func ErrnoToErr(errno syscall.Errno) error {
    if errno != 0 {
        return errno
    }
    return nil
}
```

For equality it only states

> Errno values can be tested against error values from the os package
> using errors.Is.

The question of comparing errors was already considered here [How to compare Go errors](http://How%20to%20compare%20Go%20errors)